# Battery Icon missing and settings slow 20.04

Tags: icons, battery, settings

the battery icon in the topbar is missing. There is a place for it but it is blank. The pull down menu has a blank line that expands to show "Power Settings". When I go to power settings, it takes 30 seconds to a minute to open.

I've tried reinstalling indicator-power and clearing the settings.

```
ps ax | grep indicator-power
```

returns

```
5078 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto indicator-power
```

running it with strace seems to show a number of missing files. most of them are english localization files but it looks for /etc/selinux/config and can't find it.
It also looks for a glib-2.0 file in /usr/local/share and /usr/share/ubuntu. A search of found it in /usr/share.

The trace ends with:

```
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...>) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
```

over and over.